# Cannot start MongoDB as a service after adding ips to bind_ip in mongod.cfg

Tags: mongodb, windows-10, windows-services

I am trying to enable remote connections to MongoDB server hosted in my local system and is unable to restart the MongoDB service in windows after making changes to bind_ip. The process of adding bind_ip for remote access is in the link https://mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-allow-remote-access/

I am using Windows 10

For any values of bind_ip in mongod.cfg I get this error and cannot start the service

```
# network interfaces
net:
   port: 27017
   bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
```

Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion
Error screenshot:

[image]

And the error disappears after commenting out bind_ip

```
# network interfaces
net:
   port: 27017
#   bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
```

What causes this error in windows service and how to add ips without facing error ?

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to happen because the authentication for Mongodb was disabled, as authentication was enabled the service ran without issue.